# CUDA kernel is slower than CPU

Tags: cuda, mex

I'm new to CUDA and I'm probably doing something wrong.
All I need is logical operation on two binary vectors. Length of vectors is 2048000. I compared speed between logical `and` in Matlab's C mex file and in CUDA kernel. C on CPU is ~5% faster than CUDA. Please note that I measured only kernel execution (without memory transfer). I have i7 930 and 9800GT.

```
##MEX file testCPU.c:##

#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) {
    
    int i, varLen;
    unsigned char *vars, *output;
            
    vars = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    plhs[0] = mxCreateLogicalMatrix(2048000, 1);
    output = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    for (i=0;i<2048000;i++){
        output[i] = vars[i] & vars[2048000+i];
    }
}
```

Compile

```
mex testCPU.c
```

Create vectors

```
vars = ~~(randi(2,2048000,2)-1);
```

Measure speed:

```
tic;testCPU(vars);toc;
```

**CUDA**:

```
#CUDA file testGPU.cu#
#include "mex.h"
#include "cuda.h"

__global__ void logical_and(unsigned char* in, unsigned char* out, int N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    out[idx] = in[idx] && in[idx+N];
}


void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) {
    
    int i;
    unsigned char *vars, *output, *gpu, *gpures;
    
    vars = (unsigned char*)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    
    plhs[0] = mxCreateLogicalMatrix(2048000, 1);
    output = (unsigned char*)mxGetData(plhs[0]);       
       
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    float dt_ms;
    
    // input GPU malloc
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    cudaMalloc( (void **) &gpu, sizeof(unsigned char)*4096000);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&dt_ms, start, stop);
    printf("GPU input malloc: %f ms, %i\n", dt_ms, cudaGetLastError());
    
    // output GPU malloc
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    cudaMalloc( (void **) &gpures, sizeof(unsigned char)*2048000);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&dt_ms, start, stop);
    printf("GPU output malloc: %f ms, %i\n", dt_ms, cudaGetLastError());
    
    // copy from CPU to GPU
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    cudaMemcpy( gpu, vars, sizeof(unsigned char)*4096000, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&dt_ms, start, stop);
    printf("copy input from CPU to GPU: %f ms, %i\n", dt_ms, cudaGetLastError());
    
    dim3 dimBlock(32);
    printf("thread count: %i\n", dimBlock.x);
    dim3 dimGrid(2048000/dimBlock.x);
    printf("block count: %i\n", dimGrid.x);
    
    // --- KERNEL ---
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    logical_and<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(gpu, gpures, 2048000);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&dt_ms, start, stop);
    printf("GPU kernel: %f ms, %i\n", dt_ms, cudaGetLastError());
    
    // result from GPU to CPU
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    cudaMemcpy( output, gpures, sizeof(unsigned char)*2048000, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&dt_ms, start, stop);
    printf("copy output from GPU to CPU: %f ms, %i\n", dt_ms, cudaGetLastError());
    
    
    cudaFree(gpu);
    cudaFree(gpures);
    
}
```

Compile:

```
 nvmex -f nvmexopts_9.bat testGPU.cu 
-I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include" 
-L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\lib\x64" -lcudart -lcufft
```

Output:

```
GPU input malloc: 0.772160 ms, 0
GPU output malloc: 0.041728 ms, 0
copy input from CPU to GPU: 1.494784 ms, 0
thread count: 32
block count: 64000
*** GPU kernel: 3.761216 ms, 0 ***
copy output from GPU to CPU: 1.203488 ms, 0
```

Is that code OK? CPU was ~0.1ms faster than CUDA kernel. I tried different thread counts (multipliers of 32) up to 512, 32 was fastest. Operator & instead of && was almost 1ms slower.

Is 9800GT really so weak? What speed-up can I expect with today's mainstream card (ie. GTX460,560)?

Thank you

#### EDIT: based on talonmies' comment, I made these modifications:

Kernel function:

```
__global__ void logical_and(uchar4* in, uchar4* out, int N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    out[idx].x = in[idx].x & in[idx+N].x;
    out[idx].y = in[idx].y & in[idx+N].y;
    out[idx].z = in[idx].z & in[idx+N].z;
    out[idx].w = in[idx].w & in[idx+N].w;
}
```

Main function:

```
uchar4 *gpu, *gpures;

// 32 was worst, 64,128,256,512 were similar
dim3 dimBlock(128);
// block count is now 4xtimes smaller
dim3 dimGrid(512000/dimBlock.x);
```

Output:

```
GPU input malloc: 0.043360 ms, 0
GPU output malloc: 0.038592 ms, 0
copy input from CPU to GPU: 1.499584 ms, 0
thread count: 128
block count: 4000
*** GPU kernel: 0.131296 ms, 0 ***
copy output from GPU to CPU: 1.281120 ms, 0
```

Is that correct? Almost 30x speed-up! It seems too good to be true, but result is correct :)
How faster will be GTX560 on this particular task? Thx

#### Edit 2:

Is this code

```
__global__ void logical_and(uchar4* in, uchar4* out, int N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    
    out[idx].x = in[idx].x & in[idx+N].x;
    out[idx].y = in[idx].y & in[idx+N].y;
    out[idx].z = in[idx].z & in[idx+N].z;
    out[idx].w = in[idx].w & in[idx+N].w;
}
```

automatically transformed to:

```
__global__ void logical_and(uchar4* in, uchar4* out, int N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;  
    uchar4 buff;

    buff.x = in[idx].x;
    buff.y = in[idx].y;
    buff.z = in[idx].z;
    buff.w = in[idx].w;

    buff.x &= in[idx+N].x;
    buff.y &= in[idx+N].y;
    buff.z &= in[idx+N].z;
    buff.w &= in[idx+N].w;

    out[idx].x = buff.x;
    out[idx].y = buff.y;
    out[idx].z = buff.z;
    out[idx].w = buff.w;
}
```

by compiler?

If it is correct, it explains my confusion about coalesced access. I thought that `in[idx] & in[idx+N]` leads to non-coalesced access, because of accessing non-contiguous memory. But in fact, `in[idx]` and `in[idx+N]` are loaded in two coalesced steps. `N` can be any multiple of 16, because uchar4 is 4 bytes long, and for coalesced access address must be aligned to 64 bytes (on 1.1 device). Am I right?

Comment: Your code is using byte size memory transactions, which are very suboptimal on a compute 1.1 device. Try using 32 bit memory transactions instead (so uchar4 for example) and have each thread process 4 inputs rather than 1.

Comment: Try changing block size from 32 to at least 256

Comment: In modified code, 128 worked best. 256 was almost the same (1-2% slower), 512 was ~15% slower

Comment: @eel: Be a bit careful with your `uchar4` version if you plan to run it on a Fermi or newer card. While it looks like nvopencc has compiled the kernel to use 32 bit loads and stores, you are a bit "lucky" that it did. You should explicit load the complete `uchar4` inputs to local variables, then compute the result in a local variable and store the local `uchar4` result back to global memory. The compiler(s) are much more likely to generate the code you want in that case. But 30x memory bandwidth improvement is probably about right for a compute 1.1 card.

Comment: @talonmies: This is important comment for me. Please check edit2

Comment: @talonmies: For device with compute capability 3.0, is accessing data byte-wise still a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) pointed out, you're accessing and processing your data byte-wise, which is far from optimal. A collection of techniques you may want to consider, such as Instruction-Level Parallelism and buffered read/writes, are summarized in the nVidia Webinar [Better Performance at Lower Occupancy](http://nvidia.fullviewmedia.com/gtc2010/0922-a5-2238.html) by Vasily Volkov.

In a nutshell, what you want to do is, in each thread, read *several* `uint4` in a coalesced way, process them, and only then store them.

**Update**

Does it make any difference if you re-write your code as follows?

```
__global__ void logical_and(unsigned int* in, unsigned int* out, int N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x*chunksize+threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int buff[chunksize];
    #pragma unroll
    for ( int k = 0 ; k < chunksize ; k++ )
        buff[k] = in[ blockDim.x*k + idx ];
    #pragma unroll
    for ( int k = 0 ; k < chunksize ; k++ )
        buff[k] &= in[ blockDim.x*k + idx + N ];
    #pragma unroll
    for ( int k = 0 ; k < chunksize ; k++ )
        out[ blockDim.x*k + idx ] = buff[k];
}
```

Note that I've assumed `chunksize` is a variable you've `#define`d somewhere, e.g.

```
#define chunksize 4
```

And that you have to divide the number of blocks you launch and `N` by that number. I've also used `unsigned int` which is just four packed `uchar`. In your calling function, you may have to cast your pointers accordingly.

Comment: I tried process 2 uchar4 in each thread, but the speed remains the same

Comment: Using uint4 instead of uchar4 was ~15% slower

Comment: @eel: Are you accessing them in a coalesced way? This is an important detail.

Comment: I read many materials on the coalesced memory access topic, but still I'm not sure I understand it. When the index in kernel is determined as: idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x, then memory access to array[idx] is ALWAYS coalesced (because cudaMalloc is aligned to 256 bytes). When I compute result as (array[idx] & array[idx+N]), access is NOT coalesced, because I'm accessing non-contiguous memory area. I think that the problem in my case is that second vector is located after the first one. They should be "interlaced" (to access in coalesced way). Am I right? How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: @eel: Can you post the latest version of your code as an update to your question, then I can have a look at it?

Comment: It is already there (uchar4 can be used for coalesced access as well, right?)

Comment: It's now clear I don't understand. If N (in kernel) = multiple of 16, execution speed is about 1.4x slower than N=0. But when N is multiple of 1-15, code is ~4.5x slower. Why are multiples of 16 faster then other multiples? In both cases, memory is accessed in non-coalesced way, so instruction count should be the same?

Comment: @eel: Ah, no, that's a memory alignment issue! Coalesced memory access is always faster if you read data on 16-byte boundaries!

Comment: Thank you for that code, but I can't compile it (identifier "uint" is undefined). It's strange, uint4 works.

Comment: @eel: Fixed to used `unsigned int` instead. `uint4` is four times as large and reads four times the data!

Comment: @eel: That's just to keep the reads and writes separate. I can't remember if this is what is recommended in the webinar, it's basically an extension of the `memcpy` there.

Comment: I tried your code. I got best results when `block size = 32`(128 ms, 1000 repetitions). With uchar4, best size of block was `128`, time was nearly the same (~127.3 ms). Thanks for your and talomnies' help, I've learned a lot. Could you please check edit2 in my question?

Answer (score 1):

What i think its happening is called [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). I think the problem is that the byte-sized regions you are trying to write from your threads are producing a massive race condition because different threads are trying to write to the same word-aligned address. I'm not sure the details in GPU, but in CPU, when different threads try to write to memory in the same 256-byte aligned region (called cache lines) they will continuously block each other, plummeting your global performance.